# Is it ok for react-redux to have deprecated dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-redux, babeljs, vite

When I run the command `npm ci` I get a bunch of  deprecation warnings for the following libraries:

```bash
@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator
@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding
@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator
@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
@babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions
@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
uglify-es
```

If I run `npm ls` on one of them I get stuff like this:

```bash
vite-platform@0.0.0 /Users/me/Documents/experimental/vite-platform
└─┬ react-redux@8.1.3
  └─┬ react-native@0.72.6
    ├─┬ @react-native-community/cli@11.3.7
    │ └─┬ @react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro@11.3.7
    │   └─┬ metro-react-native-babel-transformer@0.76.8
    │     └─┬ metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.76.8
    │       └── @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6 d
```

This is not a React Native project. It uses Vite and React.  Why is it still included in `react-redux` and is it safe to deploy this in production?

Comment: `react-native` is a _development_ (and optional peer) dependency of `react-redux` ([see npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux?activeTab=dependencies)), it shouldn't be installed transitively (and is not when I `npm i react-redux`).

Comment: No matter what i do, all dev dependencies are installed. Am i missing something obvious? Thanks

Comment: Also experiencing this. Removing the package and adding it back does nothing. It really wants to have those deprecated packages for some reason.